# Update multiple XML nodes that match an Xpath query C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to update the content of multiple nodes that match a specific xpath. For example, in the below example, I want to update any attribute1 node that currently is '2' with 'Hello'. What is the best way to do this?

([DotNetFiddle Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ASkFDa))

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XmlDocument job = new XmlDocument();
        job.LoadXml(@"<parent>" +
                        "<report>" +
                            "<main>" +
                                "<attribute1>2</attribute1>"+
                                "<attribute1>2</attribute1>"+
                                "<attribute1>3</attribute1>"+
                            "</main>"+
                        "</report>" +
                    "</parent>");

        string newAttribute1Value = "Hello";

        //How do I update both attribute1's where value=2? 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may could help you :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XmlDocument job = new XmlDocument();
        job.LoadXml(@"<parent>" +
                        "<report>" +
                            "<main>" +
                                "<attribute1>2</attribute1>"+
                                "<attribute1>2</attribute1>"+
                                "<attribute1>3</attribute1>"+
                            "</main>"+
                        "</report>" +
                    "</parent>");

        string newAttribute1Value = "Hello";

        //How do I update both attribute1's where value=2? 

        // getting the list of nodes with XPath query :
        XmlNodeList nodes = job.SelectNodes("//attribute1[text()=2]");
        foreach (XmlNode child in nodes)
        {
            // replacing the old value with the new value
            child.InnerText = newAttribute1Value ;
        }
    }
```